# How to get the size of the zip file without downloading the zip file?

Tags: java, gitlab

I want to get the size of the non-master branch file (zip suffix file) of the gitlab warehouse, provided that this file cannot be downloaded, how can I achieve it?Java language implementation

Comment: Do you have any experience with Java’s URL and URLConnection classes?  Showing the code you’ve written so far will give us an idea of your current knowledge level, and therefore how much explanation we need to provide.

Comment: What I want to get is the file size of a branch of gitlab. I tried this method, but the result was 404, and I also added the authentication information.
URL url = new URL("http://xxxxx/dong-test/repository/main/archive.zip");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int fileLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();

Comment: That should work for any URL.  Do you have a Java problem, or do you just need to know the correct URL for downloading a zip of a particular branch from gitlab?

Comment: I just want to know how to know the size of this branch in advance without downloading the gitlab repository file?

Comment: Your current code should work just fine.  Do you get an exception when you run it?

Comment: no，the result is always 3084

Comment: The Java code is not the problem.  The URL is the problem.